# How to allow program to take a negative key for caesar cipher encryption

Tags: java, security, caesar-cipher

I'm writing a program that takes the plaintext and encrypts it using a key (using the caesar cipher), I've gotten that program to display the ciphertext if I input a positive key. However, negative keys (say key = -1) give me an exception saying its "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 26". How can the program to loop from Z-A when its a negative key?

This is the part where it works:

```
 //if key is positive
            if(key>=0){
            // get encrypted char for each char of inputStr   
            int encryptPos = (pos+key) % 26;   
            char encryptChar = alpha.charAt(encryptPos);   
            // add encrypted char to encrypted string   
            encryptStr += encryptChar;   
              }
```

Here is where I'm facing an issue:

```
//if key is negative
              if(key<0){
            // get encrypted char for each char of inputStr 
            int encryptPos = (pos-key) %26;   
            char encryptChar = alpha.charAt(encryptPos);   
            // add encrypted char to encrypted string  
            encryptStr += encryptChar;   
              }
```

- pos is the position of the character in the alphabet.
- key must accept integers ranging from -5000 to 5000

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: @user16320675 i just edited the post with the exception, please take a look

Comment: You just need to [wrap](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/93-caesar-cipher-in-java). Doesn't matter whether +ve or -ve

Comment: @user16320675 yes! that worked! only issue is that when the key is -27 (its out of bound again) because it only looped once, how can I make it loop back even if key is (-5000)